# Jquery UI Drag And Drop add check mark to grid on drop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

A quick question maybe someone know the answer.

I have a drag and drop and I have a grid box next to it which is needed for data check, so when a draggable is dropped in I want to tick that and when it's dragged out I want untick that but not sure what to use tried over function from jQuery Ui but it did not work.

```
$('#td2').droppable({
        accept: "#r3,#r4",
        over: function( event, ui ) {
                $('#Q1v1_1').attr('checked', true);
                $('#Q1v1_1').prop('checked', true);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the `drop` event instead of the `over` event. When using `over`, the checkmark will appear on every cell you drag over.

```
$('#td2').droppable({
    accept: "#r3,#r4",
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        var $el = $(event.target),
            draggable = ui.draggable,
            drId = draggable.attr("id");
        // This is if dropping in a td and the checkbox is its child
        if (drId === "r4") {
            $el.find("input[type=checkbox]").attr('checked', 'checked');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: that's good so far just another question adds up to this, what if I want to check different check marks for different draggables. for example #r3 should enable one checkmark and #r4 another one. looking forward tp your tips

Comment: You have a reference to the draggable in the ui event arguments, so you can check which one is currently dropping.

Comment: drop: function( event, ,"#r4",)  ? is this how to refer to it.

Comment: Nope. http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop inside the event handler you can get a reference to the draggable like this: var draggable = ui.draggable;

Comment: still did not get this after reading a few times, probably because I'm new to Jquery. If you could give an example I would really appreciate it. thanks in advance!